# Is it possible Switch Screens in a TabBar navigator app without using the bottom tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I have an app that uses the tab navigator. So I have a bottom tab with the different options. On my Home tab I a "widget list" if you click on a specific widget, it should send you to that tab. Is this possible to do? you click on widget and it switches tabs, instead of having to click down on the tab navigator? if so any ideas on how to do this?

A little more background:

The home screen is in a tab navigator, but that screen contains a stack navigation. So I am trying to access the tab navigator from within the stack navigator.

in the following diagram I want to be able to go to Explore from Setting (when inside Home)

```
TabBarNavigation:

    Home
    Explore

Home (StackNavigation): 
    Main
    Settings
```

Thank you

Comment: this.props.navigate('TabName'),it also working in bottom tab navigator

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This would work if it were not embedded, check the Edit!

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('Explore') version 4x is working for me with stack navigation embedden in tabbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
onPressWidget = () => {
 this.props.navigate('widget list name')
}
```

reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, This would work if it were not embedded, check the Edit!